# Why are QUIC packets sent to Google when I am browsing other web pages?

Tags: google-chrome, protocol

Recently I discovered that when using Google Chrome, a lot of QUIC packets are being sent to Google servers even when I am browsing other web pages outside of the Google domain.

I know this is an experimental protocol developed by Google, and is used between Chrome clients and some Google services, but this does not explain why packets are sent to Google when I am browsing other web pages. Why is this?

Comment: What other websites? It's possible that they are using libraries and scripts hosted on Google's servers.

Comment: Do you have any of the synchronization features enabled?

Comment: @GiantTree: It happens only when I use Google Chrome

Comment: @DanielB: That's what I am suspecting, that Chrome is sending some kind of browsing history to Google. I just want to know why and which service is doing this.

Comment: Could you add an example of the data you have captured? Like hostnames, IP addresses or even paths?

Comment: @player Of course it sends the browsing history. If synchronization is enabled. That’s why I’m asking: Is it enabled? Are you signed in to Chrome?